# Two variables in function

Tags: theming

I know this is my fault and lack of knowledge of php . Sorry about this .
I have a function in my `template.php` .

```
/**
 * Implements THEME_preprocess_node().
 */
function salamat_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

    if ($vars['node']->type == 'article') {
        // Remove Add comment link from teaser.
        unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);

        // Remove login/register to comment link.
        unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);

  }    
}
```

When i want to add a variable like **`&$variables`** to function , it does'nt work .

```
/**
 * Implements THEME_preprocess_node().
 */
function salamat_preprocess_node(&$variables, &$vars) {

    if ($vars['node']->type == 'article') {
        // Remove Add comment link from teaser.
        unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);

        // Remove login/register to comment link.
        unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);
  }


    if($variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {

        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$variables['type'].'__teaser';
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$variables['nid'].'__teaser';
        $temp = drupal_get_query_parameters();
        if(isset($temp['show_mode']) ) {
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$variables['type'].'__teaser__'.$temp['show_mode'];
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$variables['nid'].'__teaser__'.$temp['show_mode'];
        }
    }

}
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$variables` argument is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) so you can name it whatever you want. There are two common conventions in Drupal for $variables in hook_preprocess functions:

1. Name it `$vars`
2. Name it `$variables`

I suspect you found some code that you want to use that used `$variables`; but your existing preprocess function uses `$vars`. Simply change the references to `$variables` to `$vars` in your code above and remove the `$variables` argument:

```
/**
 * Implements THEME_preprocess_node().
 */
function salamat_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  if ($vars['node']->type == 'article') {
    // Remove Add comment link from teaser.
    unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
    // Remove login/register to comment link.
    unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);
  }

  if($vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$vars['type'].'__teaser';
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$vars['nid'].'__teaser';
    $temp = drupal_get_query_parameters();
    if(isset($temp['show_mode']) ) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$vars['type'].'__teaser__'.$temp['show_mode'];
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$vars['nid'].'__teaser__'.$temp['show_mode'];
    }
  }
}
```